# The javascript code is visible on the browser

Tags: javascript, html, behavior

I just can't find the reason for that. It's quite bizarre but the javscript code is actualy visible on the browser, like it was some text displayed on the web page. It happens only on firefox. I searched all over the web on forums, websites and didn't find any answer for that behavior.
And it gets even wierder. The code displayed on the page is not even on the page´s source code. Firefox somehow picks it form I don't know where...
Does anyone knows the reason for that?

You can see it here.
http://www.rmsadv.com.br/rmac-advogados.html

Thank you all  in advance

Comment: I don't see anything like what you're describing.  Sounds like a rogue extension to me.

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong here neither.

Comment: Works okay for me in FireFox.

Comment: You do realize that PHP won't work on a plain HTML file? And CSS on the script tag is unnecessary...

Comment: Well, I'm sorry, I posted a page with the .php tag unclosed, but the error still happens on a asp page without the php tag:
http://www.rmsadv.com.br/noticias.asp

Comment: Thank you guys, @Mordred found the answer!!

Comment: Honestly, before this question I didn't realize the * selector would apply to things like scripts either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce this as well, in Chrome, (although you masked the problem by adding `style="display:none;"` to your script tag which is why no one else is seeing this). My google translate extension showed the problem as well:

[image]

Your issue is in style.css where you have this rule:

```
* {
    ...
    display: block;
    ...
}
```

You need to change that selector to be `body *` otherwise it will apply to **literally everything** on the page.

As others have mentioned you have an unclosed PHP tag (on a non-PHP page, natch), but that's not the issue here.

Also, that extra `>` on the page is not from a script but you have an extra > on the line:

```
<font class>>
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!! I've been searching for the answer for days. The incompetent HTML programmer did this. Thank you all for your patience and time!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error in Firefox, but there is a php-tag in your header which is not properly closed:

```
<body <?php="" body_class();="" ?="" style="">
```

Comment: I posted a html page with that tag problem, but even without it the problem still happens:
http://www.rmsadv.com.br/noticias.asp. I will post a screenshot

Comment: Asp won't work either. And saving as php file (as you should when using php) is not enough, your server has to run the php-interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Change it to this:-
<body <?php body_class(); ?>
```